# What is this purple stalked, berry producing plant?

Tags: identification, weeds

It has small, white flowers with 5 petals.
[image: berries]
[image: flowers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [Pokeweed, *Phytolacca americana*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pokeweed)

> a large semi-succulent herbaceous perennial plant growing up to 10 feet (3 metres) in height. It is native to eastern North America, the Midwest, and the Gulf Coast, with more scattered populations in the far West.

Also see:

- [What is this vigorous plant [duplicate]](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/what-is-this-vigorous-plant)
- [What is this fast growing plant with blue/black berries?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries)

And:

- [What is the name of this plant?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/what-is-the-name-of-this-plant) (from Biology)
- [What is the name of this big plant with a purple trunk and green to purple berries? [duplicate]](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/what-is-the-name-of-this-big-plant-with-a-purple-trunk-and-green-to-purple-berri) (from Biology)

This question has been asked a few times before.

> So clearly we need to start pokeweedID.stackexchange.com, where the only correct answer to any question will be "Phytolacca"... –  [Oreotrephes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/3952/oreotrephes) [Aug 22 at 11:10](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/what-is-the-name-of-this-big-plant-with-a-purple-trunk-and-green-to-purple-berri#comment32249_20675) (On Biology)