# Leafy plant with many small pink flowers

Tags: identification

Can anyone ID the plant pictured in [this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwndV.jpg)? It was seen earlier today (16th July) in southwest England, growing next to a road, and looks like it was coming under a fence from someone's garden. In case it's relevant, the pictures were taken at about 11 am.

[image: Album flowers.]

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwndV.jpg)</sup>

Comment: [Pokeweed _(Phytolacca americana)_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_americana)? Which would make it a duplicate of http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries, http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries and http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14020/what-is-this-purple-stalked-berry-producing-plant

Comment: I think you're right - make it an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

[Clethra alnifolia](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturallandscapesnursery.com%2Falnifolia.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturallandscapesnursery.com%2Fclethra.html&docid=pgQxEQ-KGPaBaM&tbnid=FlKGlNV6aWAt3M%3A&w=666&h=474&bih=705&biw=1455&ved=0ahUKEwjrho7UhPnNAhUU52MKHQj5AsIQMwhjKBswGw&iact=mrc&uact=8http://)  I believe it is Clethra (alnifolia).  Beautiful shrub!!  Let me know if these pictures resonate with you...!!

Comment: My clethra alnifolia does not look like the plant in these pictures. It is woody not a soft stem

Comment: Clethra IS a woody perennial/shrub...

Comment: The stems in the original posters pictures are not woody. I don't think this a clethra

Comment: Hey could be, I usually go by first instincts.  I also looked at bottlebrush.  Any other ideas? That flower spike is pretty conspicuous and not at all usual.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's pokeweed, like Niall says. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: Absolutely...Pokeweed.   Amazing...I have never encountered pokeweed but certainly a cool plant to keep, my goodness!!  I don't care if I make a mistake.  I learn and remember better from my mistakes.  There are some incredible, knowledgeable plant people on this site and I just won't allow that to scare or deter me from jumping in and making mistakes!!  Grins...