# What are these tall green plants that started growing in my garden

Tags: identification

[image: I don't know what these tall green plants are.]

Please help me identify these tall green plants they are now 3 ft high

Comment: Welcome! Where do you live?  Would you add more pictures, especially close-ups of the leaves, base & buds if there are any?  I'd check the roots and see if you can separate them without hurting the plant you like. Transplant them elsewhere and let them grow while you decide if you want them. If you throw them out now you might miss out on something fun!

Comment: Could you please give us an idea of scale: How tall are those plants?

Comment: the plants are now 3 feet high I thought everyone could enlarge the image when you click on the picture. the leaves are large green and the middle part of the plants look pinkish and has like a twist to it,

Answer (score 2):

The green ones might be pokeweed, picture is kinda small and I don't recall if it's common out west - I certainly had one pop up in my garden again this year, they are commonly spread by birds and grow fast. They are poisionous (some sources say "unless boiled" others say "period.")

Comment: If so, the canonical question/answer: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/2609/6806

Answer (score 2):

Well they look like Impatiens to me - can't see the detail of the flower, but the leaves are certainly like Impatiens walleriana, though there are other varieties. These seem a little taller than usual though, and they don't usually pop up on their own from seed, though it depends where you are to an extent. Is it possible you had some planted in that pot last year? Because if you did and they survived the winter, that would explain the increased size. Link to image (it's the first picture) here https://uk.pinterest.com/pin/562035228476275270/ They might be Impatiens New Guinea hybrids - they are taller.

If that's what they are, you can collect the seed, but when the seed pods form, you have to prepare to collect the seed before the pod explodes and shoots its contents all over the place - instructions here http://homeguides.sfgate.com/seeds-impatiens-flower-21048.html

Seeing an open flower clearly, and the seed pods as they form, would help to confirm or deny this ID too.

Comment: I tagged my posting wrong with the word seeds. I wanted to know if anyone knew what the tall green plants are in the picture. you may need to enlarge. I don't know if they are some type of plant weed or could turn out to be some type of flower? the color ones in the background I planted those they are petunias and these tall green ones come up on their own. I did not want to get rid of them in case they are something to keep around.

Comment: @FullertonCA I cannot see petunias in that pot, all I can see are two large green plants - are you saying the flowers are present on some (presumably very small) petunias? Perhaps another picture or three?

Comment: @FullertonCA - I forgot to say, I already examined your photo under magnification, and there are no visible petunia leaves

Comment: @Bamboo I think the pink plant in the back (right, between the tall unknown plant and the stars 'n stripe pinwheel) is the petunia OP mentioned.

Comment: @Stephie well I suppose it could be, although the flowers seem very small and I can't see any of its leaves

Comment: @Bamboo I asked the OP for clarification - if the pink ones are smallish petunias, the unknown plants are pretty tall.